# Why do I have activity name displayed under icon instead of application name?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inthemoon.normaltraveltracker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

where string resources are

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Normal Travel Tracker</string>
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
```

and this application icon is entitled "Map" on my Android device, i.e. not by app name but by activity name.

Why?

Comment: its clear from your question but to be sure it displays **Map** instead of  **Normal Travel Tracker** in the launcher right?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your Manifest

There are two labels you need to concern

1.For app name under... *launcher icon* -------->use `android:label` --> **inside your Main Launcher activity tag**

2.For app name under... Settings -> Application manager -> downloaded App name ---> use `android:label` -->**inside application tag**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  <----(2)
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"> < ---(1)
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Change your launcher activity `android:label` tag and run :)

**Note**: The name under the launcher icon isn't the name of the app, it's the name of the default launcher!

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by label's priority.
According to android developer API documents, 'label' in 'activity' is first priority then in 'application'.

So, you should remove 'android:label' in 'activity'.